# Using java streams, merge two maps having same keys but different values to a Tuple?

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream

I have two maps with the following data type,

```
Map<Pair<Long,String>, List<String>>  stringValues;
Map<Pair<Long,String>, List<Boolean>>  booleanValues ;
```

I want to merge the above maps to the following datastructure

```
Map<Pair<Long,String>, Pair<List<String>,List<Boolean>>>  stringBoolValues;
```

My input has two maps with same key but different values. I want to group them to a pair. Can I use java stream to achieve this ?

Comment: Question: Does your Pair class have any `set` methods?

Comment: Question: What to do when a key is present in one map but not both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

other simple way is like this:

```
stringValues.forEach((key, value) -> {
        Pair<List<String>, List<Boolean>> pair = new Pair<>(value, booleanValues.get(key));
        stringBoolValues.put(key, pair);
});
```

---

```
stringBoolValues = stringValues
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
  entry -> new Pair<>(entry.getValue(), booleanValues.get(entry.getKey()))));
```

---

Try like this:

```
Set<Pair<Long,String>> keys = new HashSet<>(stringValues.keySet());
keys.addAll(booleanValues.keySet());

keys.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key, 
           key -> new Pair<>(stringValues.get(key), booleanValues.get(key))));
```

Comment: what if few keys which are only present in booleanValues but not in stringValues ? I need them too in the stringBoolValues

Answer (score 1):

Precondition: You had overridden `equals()/hashCode()` properly for `Pair<Long, String>`

```
Map<Pair<Long,String>, Pair<List<String>,List<Boolean>>>  stringBoolValues
   = Stream.of(stringValues.keySet(),booleanValues.keySet())
      .flatMap(Set::stream)
      .map(k -> new SimpleEntry<>(k, Pair.of(stringValues.get(k), booleanValues.get(k))) 
      .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Where `Pair.of` is:

```
public static Pair<List<String>,List<Boolean>> of(List<String> strs, List<Boolean> bls) {
    List<String> left = Optional.ofNullable(strs).orElseGet(ArrayList::new);
    List<Boolean> right = Optional.ofNullable(bls).orElseGet(ArrayList::new);
    return new Pair<>(left, right);
}
```

You can even use Map.computeIfAbsent to avoid the need of explicit checking for null.

Comment: Precondition does not make any sense here.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate more??? With out properly equals overidden, you can't merge the values

Comment: `Pair, Long, String` these are the classes comprising of the key in map. Why do you think its required to override the default hashCode and equals behaviour. Default behaviour is good enough defined in these classes.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj how do you determine that “Default behaviour is good enough defined in these classes” without knowing the default behavior of the `Pair` class? There is no hint in the question, where the `Pair` class is coming from and how it has been implemented.

Comment: @Holger: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html Apache's Pair datastructure is what is being discussed here.

Answer (score 0):

Just using the `valueMapper` in [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) to *merge* values in two different maps easily:

```
Map<Pair<Long, String>, Pair<List<String>, List<Boolean>>> stringBoolValues = stringValues.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> new Pair(entry.getValue(), booleanValues.get(entry.getKey()))));
```